# How do I map a terminal command to a function key?

Tags: terminal, keyboard, command-line, bash, karabiner

I have a terminal command that can control my external display's brightness. I'm trying to map that command to a key on the keyboard so it works like a "brightness up" and "brightness down" key.

Karabiner doesn't look like it supports mapping keys to terminal commands

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use Automator to run a Shell Script and then add a keyboard shortcut to run that.

To do this:

1. Open Automator
2. Press <kbd>command</kbd><kbd>N</kbd> (or go to File > New)
3. Select the **Service** option and click on the <kbd>Choose</kbd> button
4. Make sure it's set to receive *no input* in *any application*
5. In the leftmost pane, select the **Library > Utilities** option
6. In the middle pane, double-click on the *Run Shell Script* action
7. Now enter the terminal command in the Run Shell Script window within the right pane
8. Press <kbd>command</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> (or go to File > Save...)
9. Give the Service an appropriate name
10. Click on the <kbd>Save</kbd> button
11. Now go to **Apple > System Preferences... > Keyboard**
12. Select the **Shortcuts** tab
13. Select **Services** in the left pane
14. Find and select the Service you just created in the list on the righthand side
15. Click on the <kbd>Add Shortcut</kbd> button and press the keyboard shortcut you want to use

**NOTE:** You will need to ensure it's not a shortcut already being used by macOS.

Comment: Karabiner Elements does the same with much less effort. S.th. like {"shell_command": "open -a 'Alfred 3.app'"} is really simple, defining a shortcut is done in a blink.

Answer (score 5):

I am using karabiner-elements to do exactly this on a Dell monitor, you can bind keypresses to shell commands:

```
{
"title": "F5 to dim, F6 to bright",
"rules": [
    {
        "manipulators": [
            {
              "description": "dim",
              "type": "basic",
              "from": {
                "key_code": "f5"
              },
              "to": [
                {
                    "shell_command": "/usr/local/bin/ddcctl -d 1 -b 1"
                }
              ]
            },
            {
                "description": "bright",
                "type": "basic",
                "from": {
                  "key_code": "f6"
                },
                "to": [
                  {
                      "shell_command": "/usr/local/bin/ddcctl -d 1 -b 100"
                  }
                ]
              }
          ]
    }
]
```

}

(I have ddctl installed, which lets you control the brightness by passing it a percentage value - https://github.com/kfix/ddcctl )

You can check the docs for writing your Complex Modifications like this one: https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/json.html

Comment: You're amazing  didn't realize I had to give it the full path to the binary cause it probably doesn't have those in PATH  